# PowerShell - Regex for: year, month, day, hours and minutes

Tags: regex, datetime, powershell

I currently have a String with a datetime e.g. 2013-05-09 12:13:14.000

I want to regex this to split it into seperate Year, Month, Day, Hours and Minutes variables.

```
$mCase = "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"
$tempYear = $test.column1
$year = $tempYear -replace $mCase
```

This is my first powershell script so apologies in advance if i'm being a noob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Get-Date` for this task. It outputs a `System.DateTime` object that you can perform some operations on.  Here's some [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) on the cmdlet.

```
PS C:\> $date = Get-Date "2013-05-09 12:13:14.000"
PS C:\> $date.Year
2013
PS C:\> $date.Month
5
PS C:\> $date.Day
9
PS C:\> $date.Hour
12
PS C:\> $date.Minute
13
```

To get a double-digit format, use the `-Format` method of `Get-Date` in conjunction with a specifier such as *MM* or *dd*.  A full list of .NET date and time specifiers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
PS C:\> Get-Date $date -format MM
05
PS C:\> Get-Date $date -format dd
09
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, any idea how I can use this to get the 'month' and 'day' to appear double digit format?

Comment: @user1203297 See my update.  Here's a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) to some additional formatting tips for Dates and Times.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no wierd locale issues, just use:

```
[DateTime]$MyDate = "2013-05-09 12:13:14.000"  
Write-Host $MyDate.Year
```

If you foresee locale/regional settings issues, you will have to construct a `[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]` object and use it in `[DateTime]::Parse($MyDate, $Format)`

Answer (score 1):

The answers above is the best solution, however be careful with regional settings as `datetime` uses the settings on the computer, so it might expect year-month-day and not year-day-month.

As an alternative you could use regex. It parses the string, so again if the datetime format in the string changes, then you'll have to update the code too.

```
$s = "2013-05-09 12:13:14.000"
if($s -match '(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(?:\d+)') { 
    [pscustomobject]@{ 
        Year = $Matches[1]
        Day = $Matches[2]
        Month = $Matches[3]
        Hour = $Matches[4]
        Minute = $Matches[5] 
    } 
}


Year   : 2013
Day    : 05
Month  : 09
Hour   : 12
Minute : 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can capture the relevant time parts and assign them to variables:

```
PS> $date = '2013-05-09 12:13:14.000'
PS> $year,$month,$day,$hour,$minutes,$seconds = [regex]::Matches($date,'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})').Groups | Select-Object -Skip 1 -ExpandProperty Value

PS> $year,$month,$day,$hour,$minutes,$seconds

2013
05
09
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $Date=('2013-05-09 12:13:14.000'.substring(0,10) -split '-')
 $Time=('2013-05-09 12:13:14.000'.substring(11) -split ':')
 Write-Host "The year was $($Date[0]). It was the $([int]$Date[2])$(switch ([int]$Date[2]){1{'st'}2{'nd'}3{'rd'}default{'th'}}) of $([System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.MonthNames[[int]$Date[1]]), and it was a cold morning that day. When the clock stuck $([int]$Time[0]) all hell broke lose."
```